# Scraping AJAX based value php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, domdocument, domxpath

Part of html code im trying to get info from is as follows

```
<div class="price">15</div>
```

and part of form is

```
<select name="group_1" id="group_1" class="attribute_select" onchange="findCombination();getProductAttribute();$('#wrapResetImages').show('slow');;">
    <option value="1" selected="selected" title="1">1</option>
    <option value="4" title="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Now when you change select from 1 to 4 price in div changes as the link  www.domain.com/product.html/ changes to www.domain.com/product.html#/in-pack-5. The problem is that Conbination of DOMDocument, loadHTML, DOMXPathdoesnt seem to recognize "#/in-pack-5" in the link and keeps scraping default price even when I do force "selected" to value="4".

How can I read second price than? Any ideas please as Im stuck. I would like to apologize if the question been asked already - I was searching for answer for hrs but cant find it anywhere or cant form question properply.

Thanks in advance

---

edit

Ok it seems the content (second price) is loaded by AJAX and Im told to use link below to reproduce it by php script but have no idea how to achive this

```
Request URL:https://domain.com//modules/paypal/express_checkout/ajax.php?get_qty=1&id_product=358&id_product_attribute=625&_=1436461450437
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url="https://domain.com//modules/paypal/express_checkout/ajax.php?get_qty=1&id_product=358&id_product_attribute=625&_=1436461450437";
//this line needs PHP 5.4.0+ but poster need something 5.3 compatible. $query=parse_url($url)['query'];
$query=parse_url($url);
$query=$query['query'];//for 5.3- compat.
$data=array();
parse_str($query,$data);
var_dump($data);
```

edit: wups, original answer was just half of it :p

Comment: Thanks but that gave me blank page

Comment: what version of PHP are you running? some ancient version? also, make sure error_reporting = E_ALL  in php.ini ; should give you an error telling what the problem is, not a "blank page"

Comment: php version 5.3.16. i dont have access to php.ini but error_reporting = 22527 which means pretty much all are on. But it still gives me blank page even if I include error_reporting(E_ALL) or error_reporting(-1) or  ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL) just above your code.

Comment: thanks for that but unfortunatly i just realized i wont be able to use it cos of the fact that $url is created dynamically by changing select options. So im looking for different solution.

Comment: What Im trying to do now is in php i read "option" values and push them to array, than for loop to generate javascript code:
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($select_values); $i++){ 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var select = document.getElementById("group_1");
var values = <?php echo $select_values[$i].';';?>
select.value = values;
findCombination();
getProductAttribute();
</script>
<?php
$query_price = '//span[@id="our_price_display"]';
$prices = setNodes($my_url, $query_price);
    foreach($prices as $price){
        echo $price->nodeValue;
    }
}
?>

Comment: But that code still reads same price although i can see price has changed. Forgot to mention that i loaded remote website to my domain therefore can work with javascript code on remote website.
I was also trying to store cookies in javascript and read them straight away in PHP but that didnt work either. Out of ideas now...

Comment: I think I know why... Its because although $my_url is loaded on my domain I still refer to remote website when I  $prices = setNodes($my_url, $query_price); so my question now is how can I refer to my domain with remote website loaded in it to get the prices?

Answer (score 0):

What Ive figured out is I could loop through option values and change them by echoing javascript code and that works for getting the values and even changing the state of select form. Than I wanted to echo onchange(); but that doesnt work. How can i force onchange() on select form through php by echoing javascript code?

I tried

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var select = document.getElementById("group_1");        
    var option = select.getElementsByTagName("option");
    for(j=0; j < option.length; j++){
        option[j].removeAttribute("selected");
    }
    option['.$i.'].setAttribute("selected","selected");
    select.onchange();

</script>';
```

which works in console but not by echoing by php